# How to find location of roots of a polynomial without actually solving it?

Tags: polynomials, roots

For e.g:Let the question be:

> Q)Locate the roots of the following polynomial:$$f(x)=x^3-6x+2$$

For this,by putting various values and by bruteforcing,we see that the polynomial changes sign at -2,1,3 and thereby making the roots lie in $(-\infty,-2),(-2,1),(1,3)$.However,in the book the answer is more precise and given as $(-3,-1),(0,1),(1,3)$.How did this come as -3,-1 and 0 are not leading to sign change specifically as there is a sign change for (-3,1),(-4,1) and (-5,1),(-3,-2) too ?

 Also,how can this be done for the general equation$$f(x)=a_1x^n+a_2x^{n-1}+.......+a_{n-1}x+a_n$$without actually solving it?

Comment: $f(-3)<0, f(-1)>0$, yes?

Comment: Without mechanical assistance, it can be difficult to say much about general polynomials.  Did you have something specific in mind?

Comment: $f(-3)<0$ and $f(-1)>0$.  Why do say there is no sign change on $(-3,-1)$?  Same question for the other intervals.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-root_isolation

Comment: @saulspatz There is a sign change for (-3,1) but so is for (-4,1) and (-5,1),(-3,-2)I want to ask.I wanted to as why were only those intervals chosen in the book?

Comment: Did you look at Trevor's answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
x & -3 & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\ \hline
f(x) & -7& 6 & 7 & 2 & -3 & -2 & 11
\end{array} $$

So the sign changes between $-3$ and $-2$, between $0$ and $1$ and between $2$ and $3$.